# Dojo on widget load event

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I'd like to know when a Dojo form widget is parsed or ready so I can customize it dynamically. I am trying to achieve this by using the `dojo.connect()` method. However, I am not sure what event to listen to. Is it `onLoad` or `onStartup` or..?

This is what I have done but it isn't triggering:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('myWidget'), 'onStartup', function(evt) {
   console.debug("test");
}
```

note that the `dijit.byId('myWidget')` part returns the object correctly so that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It depends somewhat on what exactly you are trying to customize (see the widget lifecycle [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/_Widget.html)) but I would guess that connecting to `postCreate` will satisfy your requirements

Answer (score 2):

to answer my own question, there is a "startup" function in the widget lifecycle so I can use that instead of "onStartup" like so:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('myWidget'), 'startup', function(evt) {
   console.debug("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to wait for an external template. I made it like this:

```
var myCp= registry.byId("myContentPane");
myCp.set("onDownloadEnd", function(){
    console.log("Download complete!");
});
myCp.set("href", "myHtml.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wrap that code with a `dojo.addOnLoad()` function call you should be good.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/addOnLoad.html

Comment: The widgets are parsed dynamically and loaded via AJAX calls. What you are propsing only works when the page loads but not after.